# What is the meaning of pos1 and pos2 under sort -k?

Tags: sort

I want to understand the exact meaning of pos1 and pos2 under `sort -k`

According to the manual

> -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>
> See POS syntax below.Start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line).

What exactly do pos1 and pos2 mean?

Could anyone explain it clearly in simple terms?

Thanks!

Comment: a good explanation here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255696/what-is-meant-by-k1-1-in-sort?rq=1

Comment: "See POS syntax below" ... So did you see the description of the syntax below that? What about it is unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help show the difference:

```
$ cat lines.txt
c 1 a
b 2 a
c 3 c
a 3 a
a 2 c
a 1 b
b 1 c
c 2 b
b 3 b
```

Sorting by second field (unrestricted):

```
$ sort -k2 lines.txt
c 1 a
a 1 b
b 1 c
b 2 a
c 2 b
a 2 c
a 3 a
b 3 b
c 3 c
```

Sorting by second field and restricted to second field:

```
$ sort -k2,2 lines.txt
a 1 b
b 1 c
c 1 a
a 2 c
b 2 a
c 2 b
a 3 a
b 3 b
c 3 c
```

Notice the change in the third field.